# Permissions Exception Rebuilding Link Database

Tags: link-database, broken-links

One of our users recently got this exception while trying to rebuild the links database it the Scan the database for broken links (report) dialog:

[image]

I'm not clear what access is being denied here, and why.  Is this a Sitecore user access issue, or is it more on the lines of a database issue?  If the former, what sort of permissions is he likely to be missing?  (He currently has fairly basic access to one project - basically a subtree of the content tree.  I understand the link database is shared across multiple database environments; does it therefor require a higher level of access to run this update?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `core` database there is `Rebuild link database` application. You can find it here:

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/Control Panel/Database/Rebuild link database
```

That `Application access denied` exception is thrown when that item is either missing in `core` database or when the user does not have `Read` access to that item.

If it was one time issue only, most probably user was logged out in the meantime between opening the `Browser Links` dialog and opening `Rebuild link database` form.

If it's permanent, check if that user has access to the item mentioned above using `Access viewer`.